# Call function/add own code after Order in Opencart

Tags: php

i'm working on Open Cart 3.0.2.0.
I want to call my own function after someone buy a product from my store. Where i can call this function? I tried to put the test code in catalog/model/checkout/order.php in addOrder and addOrderHistory methods, also in catalog/controller/chekout/confirm.php but it doesn't work.. Can anyone know in which file and method i should put my own code?

There is piece of my test code:

```
<?php
class ModelCheckoutOrder extends Model {
    public function addOrder($data) {
        //TEST
        file_put_contents('my_directory/test.txt', 'test');
        ...
```

Edit: I know that in older versions was Confirm method i Checkout Model, and there u could pass your code, but it disappeared in new versions.

I can put my code in catalog/controller/success.php, but i need to get and pass informations about all ordered products. Any ideas?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer few days ago. The first option is get order id from session in "success.php" file and work with it.

Or (second option) you can edit files in the system/storage/modification !